# Why do I keep getting a status code 403 in a http request even after adding CORS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, xmlhttprequest

When I try to make a http request in Angular in the front-end of my application, I can't complete the request as I get the status code 403 in a preflight request. I already set the headers in the Node.js in the back-end for allowing the accessing, but I still get the error, for both GET or POST requests. I also read some answers here and they basically say to set the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin as *, but that didn't work.

Here is my front-end:

```
 $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "http://localhost:8080/v1/get-mac",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Authorization': "token"
        }
        }).then(function(response) {
            this.machines = response.data;
        });
```

And this is what I did in the backend with Express:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  next();
});
```

The error I get in Chrome is:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/v1/get-mac
  (anonymous function) @ angular.js:12011
  sendReq @ angular.js:11776
  serverRequest @ angular.js:11571
  processQueue @ angular.js:16383
  (anonymous function) @ angular.js:16399
  $eval @ angular.js:17682
  $digest @ angular.js:17495
  $apply @ angular.js:17790
  (anonymous function) @ angular.js:25890
  defaultHandlerWrapper @ angular.js:3497
  eventHandler @ angular.js:3485
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/v1/get-mac    
  Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

Why is that happening? Already tried lots of things, but I don't know why even with setting the response header it doesn't work. Thanks

Here is my app.js:

```
var server = require(__dirname + '/server.js')();

var app = server.app.express();

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  next();
});

app.use(server.app.express.static(server.app.path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.use(server.app.morgan('dev'));
app.engine('html', server.app.ejs.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(server.app.methodOverride());
app.use(server.app.bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(server.app.bodyParser.json());

server.router(app);

return server.app.http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function() {
  console.log("Server is on, listening on: 8080");
});
```

Comment: Why is your back-end server code responding to an OPTIONS request with 403? Make your server respond to OPTIONS requests with a 200 response instead. You haven't shown any back-end code that would cause a 403 response, so I can't tell you *how* to fix that in your code, though.

Comment: To put it another way: you seem to think the CORS header is somehow causing a 403 response, but the ultimate fact is that a 403 response is causing a CORS failure. Fix your server code so that it doesn't respond with 403 when it gets an OPTIONS request, and your client-side CORS error will go away.

Comment: Why do you have `'Content-Type': "application/json",`? You are making a GET request. There is no content to describe the type of.

Answer (score -1):

The server should send a "200" response to the OPTIONS request.
So modify your server code to:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,     
                                               Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        return res.status(200)
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: If the requested origin is different from the origin of the current page, how are you supposed to specify the target origin, then? If OP's code is in a page on `example.com` and you want to send a request for `http://localhost:8080/v1/get-mac`, then you need to specify that your target is `localhost:8080` *somewhere*.

Comment: Look at the edited answer. And the error Luiz getting is not from the server but from the browser. The browser won't allow any CORS request to pass through without those headers set

Comment: To your edit: this is exactly what the OP's code is already doing; CORS headers are are automatically added by the browser when a cross-origin request is sent.

Comment: The error is from the browser, but the browser is producing an error because the server is responding to the  CORS OPTIONS preflight with a 403 response, which terminates the request in an error state. The solution here is "stop the server from sending a 403 response". (See [preflight steps of the CORS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0), which includes the directions, "If the response has an HTTP status code that is not in the 2xx range:
Apply the network error steps.")

Comment: Yeah, I realise my mistake.

Comment: So, the server should send 200 OK to the OPTIONS. But there's no response from the server.

Comment: Well, there *is* a response from the server; the response is `403 Forbidden`. This response causes the preflight to fail, which causes the whole request to fail. (As I mentioned in a comment on the question, the question does not have any code that would produce a 403 response, so we can't make any specific guesses how to fix the server so it sends 200 instead.)

Comment: I wasn't able to fix the code, I don't know where the server is responding with a 403. In the question I added the app.js code, could you help me please?

Comment: When I try to access the endpoint with Postman, it works well

Comment: Change your code to what I have posted and see if the problem persists

Comment: When I try your code, I get the following message in the browser: OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/v1/get-mac net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: That's because you don't have a response for "/v1/get-mac"